# Increasing the space between the following two lines

Tags: beamer, line-spacing

How to increase the space between the following two lines?

[image: Output]

Here is what I have tried:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%-----
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts} 
\usepackage{pifont}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \centerline{\ding{45} $\mathcal{N}(T)$ is called the null space of $T$.}
        \ding{43} The range of $T$ is given by
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding `\vspace{1cm}` before `\ding{43}`? Change value `1cm` for your needs ...

See the following mwe

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts} 
\usepackage{pifont}
\usetheme{Madrid}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \centerline{\ding{45} $\mathcal{N}(T)$ is called the null space of $T$.}
  \vspace{1cm} % <======================================================
  \ding{43} The range of $T$ is given by
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting pdf]

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways: if you are going to use `\centerline` frequently throughout your presentation, then I suggest to redefine it as:

```
\renewcommand{\centerline}[1]{\null\hfill#1\hfill\null~\\[2ex]}
```

The second way is to use ~\ right after `\centerline{...}`, *i.e.,* `\centerline{...}~\\`

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%-----
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts} 
\usepackage{pifont}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\renewcommand{\centerline}[1]{\null\hfill#1\hfill\null~\\[2ex]} % Need this!
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \centerline{\ding{45} $\mathcal{N}(T)$ is called the null space of $T$.}
        % Or just use the following and you don't need to redefine the command:
        % \centerline{\ding{45} $\mathcal{N}(T)$ is called the null space of $T$.}~\\
        \ding{43} The range of $T$ is given by
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```